# Настройка smtp-сервера для яндекс PDD

Tags: php, ubuntu, postfix, exim, яндекс-почта

Решил я настроить *postfix* на своем сервере, основная задача - отправлять письма из `mail()` *php*, через аккаунт в *яндекс пдд* («почта для доменов»).

Делал я все по данной инструкции: http://onedev.net/post/277

кажется все довольно просто, но у меня ничего не работает, в итоге совсем не понятно что вышло, вот лог `/var/log/mail.log`:

```
Jun 28 23:16:23 server postfix/pickup[9768]: A7FB7630E1: uid=1000 from=<sanu>
Jun 28 23:16:23 server postfix/cleanup[12565]: A7FB7630E1: message-id=<20150628201623.A7FB7630E1@server.localdomain>
Jun 28 23:16:23 server postfix/qmgr[9769]: A7FB7630E1: from=<sanu@server.localdomain>, size=530, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 28 23:16:23 server postfix/local[12710]: warning: database /etc/aliases.db is older than source file /etc/aliases
Jun 28 23:16:23 server postfix/local[12710]: warning: dict_nis_init: NIS domain name not set - NIS lookups disabled
Jun 28 23:16:23 server postfix/local[12710]: A7FB7630E1: to=<root@server.localdomain>, orig_to=<root>, relay=local, delay=0.01, delays=0/0/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Jun 28 23:16:23 server postfix/qmgr[9769]: A7FB7630E1: removed
```

Вообще ничего не пойму что к чему. Раннее было проще, был *win server*, в котором в *sendmail.ini* прописывалось все до банальности просто.

Может, *postfix* не лучший вариант? подскажите что выбрать в таком случае? или есть какая-либо более разжеванная для нубов инструкция по настройке *постфикса* в случае с *яндекс пдд*?

p.s.
В моем случае, письмо никуда не приходит, а в *php* `mail()` возвращает `true`

Comment: 1. письмо благополучно пришло: предпоследняя строка извещает, что оно доставлено в *mailbox* пользователя `root@server.localdomain`. 2. скажите, а зачем вам нужно, чтобы письма уходили «кружным» путём, через яндексовские серверы? у вас внешний ip постоянно меняется?

Comment: нет, ip статический, но из за того что нет возможности сделать нормальную PTR - письма летят в спам, а через яндекс - норм

Answer (score 1):

передача почты яндексовским серверам имеет смысл только в том случае, если ваш почтовый сервер не имеет фиксированного внешнего ip-адреса. если это так (или требуется по каким-то не-техническим причинам), то вот инструкция:

в случае *ubuntu* я бы порекомендовал использовать не *postfix*, а *exim*: по-моему, он несколько проще в настройке для типовых случаев использования.

- установите пакет: `sudo apt-get install exim4`.
- в файл `/etc/exim4/passwd.client` добавьте строку (с актуальными данными учётной записи и пароля, под которыми надо аутентифицироваться на яндексе):

  ```
  smtp.yandex.ru:user@domain.ru:пароль
  ```
- если при установке не предлагалась настройка, то после установки запустите её командой `sudo dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config`. дальше будет про то, что вписывать в диалоги настройки (с пояснениями в скобках):

1. «mail sent by smarthost; no local mail» (выберите этот пункт из списка)
2. «some-server.domain.ru» (если домен на яндексе прописан как `domain.ru`)
3. «127.0.0.1» (IP-addresses to listen on for incoming SMTP connections — на каком адресе принимать почту)
4. «» (Other destinations for which mail is accepted — оставить пустым, стерев то, что там может быть подставлено)
5. «domain.ru» (Visible domain name for local users)
6. «smtp.yandex.ru:587» (smarthost)
7. «yes» (Keep number of DNS-queries minimal)
8. «yes» (Split configuration into small files)

собственно, всё.

---

можно сразу и протестировать. одним из способов (зависит от того, какая именно программа установлена в качестве `mail`). либо так (от пользователя `user1@domain.ru` пользователю `user2@domain.ru`):

```
$ echo body | mail -r user1@domain.ru -s subject user2@domain.ru
```

либо так:

```
$ echo body | mail -a "From: user1@domain.ru" -s subject user2@domain.ru
```