# exim4 не хочет отправлять письма

Tags: ubuntu, exim4

У меня есть сайт, есть yandex pdd
В файле `/etc/exim4/passswd.client` я прописал

```
smtp.yandex.ru:service@home-android.ru:mypasswd
```

25й порт доступен.

`При конфигурировании, на первом шаге я выбрал:` интернет сайт прием и отправка почты напрямую

`почтовое имя системы:` home-android.ru

`IP-адреса, с которых следует ожидать входящие соединения SMTP:` 127.0.0.1

`Другие места назначения, для которых должна приниматься почта:` пусто

`Домены, для которых доступна релейная передача почты:` home-android.ru; mx.yandex.ru; yandex.ru

`Машины, для которых доступна релейная передача почты:` пусто

`Сокращать количество DNS-запросов до минимума:` нет

`Метод доставки локальной почты:` Maildir формат в домашнем каталоге

`Разделить конфигурацию на маленькие файлы:` нет

В итоге, при попытке отправить письмо на 0074.sanu@gmail.com - ничего не приходит, в логе я получаю вот что:

```
    2016-05-16 00:22:59 1b23V5-0007Fp-Ro <= service@home-android.ru U=www-data P=local S=1564
2016-05-16 00:22:59 1b23V5-0007Fp-Ro gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [2a00:1450:4010:c09::1a] Network is unreachable
2016-05-16 00:23:02 1b23V8-0007GD-7y <= root@home-android.ru U=root P=local S=1091
2016-05-16 00:23:07 1abPbB-0005uv-3g mx.yandex.ru [77.88.21.89] Connection timed out
2016-05-16 00:23:09 1adDt6-0006Tq-U4 mx.yandex.ru [213.180.193.89] Connection timed out
2016-05-16 00:23:09 1adDt6-0006Tq-U4 mx.yandex.ru [93.158.134.89] No route to host
2016-05-16 00:23:09 1adDt6-0006Tq-U4 mx.yandex.ru [213.180.204.89] No route to host
2016-05-16 00:23:09 1adDt6-0006Tq-U4 mx.yandex.ru [87.250.250.89] No route to host
2016-05-16 00:23:09 1adDt6-0006Tq-U4 == root@home-android.ru R=dnslookup_relay_to_domains T=remote_smtp defer (113): No route to host
2016-05-16 00:23:09 1adDt6-0006Tq-U4 ** root@home-android.ru: retry timeout exceeded
2016-05-16 00:23:09 1b23VF-0007HH-31 <= <> R=1adDt6-0006Tq-U4 U=Debian-exim P=local S=2210
2016-05-16 00:23:09 1adDt6-0006Tq-U4 Completed
```

Почему письма не доставляются? Что может быть причиной?

Comment: 1. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/432526/178576 2. *no route to host* — перевод: нет маршрута к хосту. вероятно, отсутствует либо неработоспособен маршрут по умолчанию. проверьте настройки сети.

Comment: Спасибо) Сделал, работает!